# Mapping a 2d list and a 1d list on to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list-

`index = ['a','b','c','d']`

And a 2 dimensional list-
`val = [[1,11,21,31],[3,13,23,33],[7,17,27,37]]`

How do I map these arrays in a dictionary so that the values are as follows-

`d = {'a': [1,3,7] ,'b': [11,13,17] ,'c': [21,23,27] ,'d': [31,33,37] }`.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I suppose doing it by looping over the 2d list is not very efficient?
Is there any way to do it by using the `dict(zip()` function, i.e. the way we do it when we map two 1d lists?

I tried it using `dict(zip(index,val))`. But it gives me

`d = {'a' : [1,11,21,31], 'b' : [3,13,23,33], 'c' : [7,17,27,37]`

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val` has shape `(3,4)`, but in order to form a `dict` using `zip`, the first dimension has to match the number of indices: in this case, 4.  You can achieve this by transposing `val`.

To transpose a list of lists:

```
>>> zip(*val)
[(1, 3, 7), (11, 13, 17), (21, 23, 27), (31, 33, 37)]
```

You can then zip the result together with the indices to form a `dict`:

```
>>> dict(zip(index, zip(*val)))
{'d': (31, 33, 37), 'a': (1, 3, 7), 'b': (11, 13, 17), 'c': (21, 23, 27)}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
index = ['a','b','c','d']
val = [[1,11,21,31],[3,13,23,33],[7,17,27,37]]

print dict(zip(index, zip(*val)))
```

Output:

```
{'a': (1, 3, 7), 'c': (21, 23, 27), 'b': (11, 13, 17), 'd': (31, 33, 37)}
```

If you need list instead of tuple.

```
print dict(zip(index, [list(i) for i in zip(*val)]))
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 3, 7], 'c': [21, 23, 27], 'b': [11, 13, 17], 'd': [31, 33, 37]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
index = ['a','b','c','d']
val = [[1,11,21,31],[3,13,23,33],[7,17,27,37]]

>>> print map(list,zip(*val))
[[1, 3, 7], [11, 13, 17], [21, 23, 27], [31, 33, 37]]

>>> print dict(zip(index,map(list,zip(*val))))
{'a': [1, 3, 7], 'c': [21, 23, 27], 'b': [11, 13, 17], 'd': [31, 33, 37]}
```